# Thread local variables and fs segment

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, gcc, x86-64

I am reading from a thread local variable in my code like this,

```
// tid_local is declared as __thread int tid_local;
long tid = tid_local
```

Looking around the dissassembled code, I saw something like this, which I suspect is the instruction which assigns **tid** by reading **tid_local**.

```
movslq %fs:0xfffffffffffffffc,%rbx
```

Now my question is if this can really be the instruction which is doing this, that is, reading from the local thread variable and if gcc always uses the **fs** segment for storing thread local variables. How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, this could well be the right instruction. From the `gcc` [manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.0/gcc/i386-and-x86_002d64-Options.html):

> `-mtls-direct-seg-refs`
>
> `-mno-tls-direct-seg-refs`
>
> Controls whether TLS variables may be accessed with offsets from the TLS segment register (**%gs for 32-bit, %fs for 64-bit**), or whether the thread base pointer must be added. Whether or not this is legal depends on the operating system, and whether it maps the segment to cover the entire TLS area.

**edit** Here is an excellent link suggested by @janneb in the comments: http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf

Comment: But how is this supposed to work. How different threads have different fs segments?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: Well, each thread has its own set of register values (for **all** registers, not just `fs`).

Comment: About the registers, yes I know that each thread has its own. But I'm a bit surprised about fs. My guess is that fs segment must not be very large, otherwise it would have to be saved each time context switch occurs.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: The segment isn't saved, it's the **value of the register pointing to the segment** that gets saved. Each thread has a different value of `fs`.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: You can read how TLS works on Linux at http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf

Comment: @aix, interesting, x86 architects are pretty clever to devise such a scheme :)!

Answer (score 1):

The way different threads can have different fs segments is implemented by setting up local descriptor tables (LDTs) on a per-thread basis. When a thread switch occurs the processor automatically loads the any "thread-local" segment descriptors from the corresponding LDT. You can verify if that's the case by looking at the value of FS. If bit 3 is 1 then it is using an LDT.

Ex. FS = 1B (which happens to be the usual "CS" selector for under Win NT) is a thread-local segment.

You work it out as follows:

The selector in binary is

0000 0000 0001 1011

or

Index=0000 0000 0001 [12 bits] (2nd entry in DT)

Descriptor Table=1 [1 bits] (1 == local, 0 == global)

RPL=011 [3 bits] (Requested Privilege level = 3)

- Alan

Comment: I think this is incorrect, RPL is only last 2 bits, not 3, and the 0 before them means GDT; AFAIU, LDT is forbidden to use on Windows and is (almost) unused on Linux